# Add certain values from JSON object to javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

**Update:** I've tried the suggestions in the comments and it's still not working. I really have no idea why. I've consolidated it to a single loop and fixed the syntax errors noted. Here's the code as it looks now:

```
    $(function() {

  $("#json-one").change(function() {

    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $.getJSON("washroutines.json", function(data) {

      var vals = [];
      var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
$jsontwo.empty();        

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if (data[i].make === $dropdown.val()) {
          $jsontwo.append("<option value=\"" + data[i].model + "\">" + data[i].model + "</option>");
        }
      }

    });
  });

});
```

Any additional help would be much appreciated!

Original question:

I'm trying to create dependent drop down menus using a json object, and I'm having trouble getting the second menu to populate based on the first. When the first menu changes, the second goes to a bunch of "undefined"s.

```
    $.getJSON("washroutines.json", function(data) {     
      var vals = [];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
 if (data.make = $dropdown.val()) {
   vals.push(data.model);
   }
  }

      var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
      $jsontwo.empty();
   for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
   $jsontwo.append("<option value\"" + vals[i] + "\">" + vals[i] + "</option>");
}
```

Please use small words when explaining things to me, I'm new at this!

contents of the JSON:

```
[{"make":"Maytag","model":"Bravos","prewashCycle":"Whitest Whites"},
{"make":"Maytag","model":"Awesome","prewashCycle":"Awesome Whitest Whites"},
{"make":"Whirlpool","model":"Cabrio","prewashCycle":"Extra Heavy"},
{"make":"Kenmore","model":"Elite","prewashCycle":"Awesome"}]
```

Comment: please add the content of the JSON string/washroutines.json.

Comment: Presumably `data.model` is undefined then?

Comment: (and please, please, please, indent your code to make it clear where the nesting is)

Comment: Show us the expected data structure. Or even better create a CodePen

Comment: if (data.make = $dropdown.val()) won't work as an operator, you should use == for equality regardless of type or === for equality of value and type

Comment: I added the contents of the json. 
I don't know what a CodePen is, sorry! 
I tried switching the operator to == but now I don't even get undefineds.

Comment: You're not getting anything because the field data.make doesn't exist, data is an array, not an object, so to access the objects inside you have to add an index to data, i.e. data[i].make and data[i].model

Comment: Is there any reason your using 2 for loops?  Why not just have one loop through the result and append the values from the object directly to the drop down?  Something like data[i].model or data[i].make.

Comment: No reason for two loops. I'll try consolidating it.

Comment: Updated the question with the suggestions made here, still not working, and I'm still at a loss.

Comment: add console.log(data[i]); after the for line and check your console to see if you're actually processing anything

Comment: That helped! I wasn't getting anything, and I finally thought to check my HTML and discovered the values of my drop down menu were not capitalized, but the values in my JSON object are. Fixed that, and now it works. What a stupid error! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your for loop for this

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if (data[i].make === $dropdown.val()) {
    vals.push(data[i].model);
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. it does nothing when the first menu is changed, and when you click on the second menu, it goes from "please select" to blank.

Comment: your option tag also has a problem, you're missing the '=' after value, i.e.
'<option value="' + vals[i] + '">' + vals[i] + '</option>'